# Django debug toolbar showing on bottom of page

Tags: django, django-debug-toolbar

I'm trying to add Django-debug-toolbar to my website to troubleshoot some problems. I followed the installation process and have some results, but not what I expected. There is some information showing on the bottom of the page, but there is no toolbar on the right. This half result shows on every page at the very bottom.

I followed the instruction page from the autors, as well as several youtube guides. I googled this problem but didn't see anyone with the same issue.

What I did:
- Installed django-debug-toolbar using pip
- Added debug_toolbar to INSTALLED_APPS
- Added 'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware' to the end of the middleware list
- Added INTERNAL_IPS = ('127.0.0.1)
- Added the DEBUG_TOOLBAR_PANELS list
- Added the optional 'show_toolbar' variable, just to be sure
- Checked the body /body tags
- Added the 'if settings.debug' statement in the urls.py

Here is a picture of the result. https://i.stack.imgur.com/L3CqE.jpg

The debugger seems to work, it's just the formatting which does not seem to function. Does anyone know where the problem might be?

Comment: It looks as if the static files are not being served. If you check your browser tools you will probably see 404s. You haven't given any details of how you are serving static files, but running `manage.py collectstatic` might be enough.

Comment: It seems like I'm getting error 403 for the debug toolbar. 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)

Comment: Thanks man, the collectstatic command did the trick. Very much appreciated!